# Cannot Resolve Style, ResourceDictionary, UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

This is by far the most perplexing problem I have faced in WPF in the year that I have worked on it. There are two components to the problem that may indicate more to those of you who have worked with WPF for longer:

1. In a `UserControl`, my `ResourceDictionary` element complains that it requires a `Key` attribute.
2. When I define the `Key` attribute and attempt to access the styles at design time from XAML, the Intellisense (and compiler) is unaware of the styles defined in my imported `ResourceDictionary`.
3. I am attempting to apply the style to an .`ItemTemplate` on a `MenuItem`

Here is my `UserControl` XAML declaration of the resource, *note the `x:Key` attribute*.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HeaderViewStyles">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Styles/Controls/HeaderViewStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Here is a partial implementation of the `ResourceDictionary`, defining the style I wish to use on a `MenuItem`.

```
x:Class="Styles.Controls.HeaderViewStyles">

<Style x:Key="DarkMenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">

 <!---
```

There may be a problem with the above style, itself; however, what I am interested in is *why I cannot access the style at design time*.

Here's my attempt to apply the style (posting for full information):

```
     <Menu>
        <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItemViewModels}">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="../../Resources/menu.png"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controlViewModels:ContextMenuItemViewModel}">
                    <MenuItem Style="{DynamicResource DarkMenuItem}"
                        Header="{Binding MenuHeaderText}"
                        Command="{Binding MenuItemClickedCommand}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

I am sure this is a combination of factors; however, I am clearly lacking some knowledge. What am I missing or not doing? I've tried various combinations, yet still can't get the style picked up.

**EDIT**

For those who want more information, here is my control XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.Controls.HeaderView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:controlViewModels="clr-namespace:ViewModels.Controls"
         xmlns:controlViews="clr-namespace:Views.Controls"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Converters"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         Background="#4C4C4C">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:SyncStateToVisibilityConverter x:Key="SyncStateToVisibilityConverter"/>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HeaderViewStyles">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Styles/Controls/HeaderViewStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Background="#4C4C4C" Margin="20,0,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Command="{Binding StatusButtonClickedCommand}">
        <Image >
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding StatusIconLocation}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding StatusIconLocationHover}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </Button>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <Menu>
        <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItemViewModels}">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="../../Resources/menu.png"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controlViewModels:ContextMenuItemViewModel}">
                    <MenuItem Style="{DynamicResource DarkMenuItem}"
                        Header="{Binding MenuHeaderText}"
                        Command="{Binding MenuItemClickedCommand}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                Value="{Binding PercentageSynced}"
                Visibility="{Binding CurrentSyncSystemStatus, 
                            Converter={StaticResource SyncStateToVisibilityConverter}, 
                            ConverterParameter=Syncing, 
                            FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You don't need x:Key attribute on that ResourceDictionary.

Comment: @Evk the compiler complains if it isn't there. Note point no. 1. This is why I am so muddled.

Comment: Well it should not complain. Please provide full xaml of your UserControl.

Comment: @Evk provided. Let me know if I can provide anything, else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your converter inside resource dictionary, and remove x:Key, like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Styles/Controls/HeaderViewStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <converters:SyncStateToVisibilityConverter x:Key="SyncStateToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

If you put ResourceDictionary without a key as a root of `UserControl.Resources` - it means this:

```
userControl.Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
```

So you have to put every other resources *inside* that dictionary, not outside.

Your original xaml (with x:Key) means roughly this:

```
userControl.Resources.Add("SyncStateToVisibilityConverter", new YourConverter());
userControl.Resources.Add("HeaderViewStyles", new ResourceDictionary(...));
```

So, not quite what you expect.

Comment: That did it! Thank you for the explanation. That's exactly what I was missing.